# Possible Bug - My material color won't change

Tags: materials

This is in Material Preview shading mode. As you can see the colors chosen in the nodes do not correspond the one showing in the viewport for the sphere. Same thing for the Object Properties/Viewport Display. If I apply a 2 nodes material then it’s ok. But there is something with these set of nodes that won’t pass the color chosen in the nodes to the object. It did belong to a more complex set of nodes. This one is a simplified iteration (for troubleshooting).

[image]

This is in Solid shading mode:

[image]

Can someone pls inspect the .blend file? 
[badmaterial.blend (833.8 KB)](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/eN4A0u3jRnSQFyAq6TKzkWNigNN.blend)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have deleted something from the original node network.

Your color ramp is not driven by any coordinate based texture so you will only get a solid color (assuming the same color at every point on the sphere). Since your ramp is a gradient of grey and you are mixing it 50% with black, you end up with a middle grey solid diffuse color! No surprise there!

To see the effect of the ramp, simply add a texture that's based on some sort of coordinates for example a `Musgrave Texture`, a `Noise Texture` or a `Voronoi Texture` would do. So would an `Image Texture`...

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bruno. I also noticed that if I slide the left Gradient tick to the right, THEN I can see that tick color in the object (which is what I needed). I really don't need a gradient, I just wanted a means to have a solid color here, but I didn't find any other way. Thanks a bunch again!

Comment: Well if you want a solid color, just remove Mix, ColorRamp and Musgrave Texture nodes and use the Diffuse BSDF color input (click on it to select your color!)